# Why document.getElementById("id") it does not work?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code( to draw a map using google map API V3):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% ; width:100%;}
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        var previousPosition = null;

        function initialize() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                zoom: 19,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.858565, 2.347198),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              });
        }

        if (navigator.geolocation)
          var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, null, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
        else
          alert("Votre navigateur ne prend pas en compte la géolocalisation HTML5");

        function successCallback(position){
          map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
            map: map
          });
          if (previousPosition){
            var newLineCoordinates = [
               new google.maps.LatLng(previousPosition.coords.latitude, previousPosition.coords.longitude),
               new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)];

            var newLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: newLineCoordinates,
              strokeColor: "#FF0000",
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2
            });
            newLine.setMap(map);
          }
          previousPosition = position;
        };
      </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="initialize()">
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

it works very well(you can test it), but when i put :

```
<div id="a">
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

instead of:

```
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

it does not work anymore...

why it does not work in the second version ?

PS: I have just given a simple code that represents my real code(just so you understand more easily)...

**EDIT**:
I do not really understand, I think this is a problem of selector ... as said Michael Haren.

I tried to do this in my code but when i click in 'click me' it does not work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
<style>
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
/*
 #content,#right = #a,#map_canvas{..
*/
#content,#right { width:70%; height: 100%;margin-left:2%;  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 5px #aaa; }

</style>


<title>Géolocalisation restreinte</title>
<%@include file="includes/head.html" %>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function drawMap(){
   var locTunisie= new google.maps.LatLng(33.858565, 10.347198);
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("right"), {
            zoom: 6,
            center:locTunisie,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          });     
}



</script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- iclure le  header-->
<%@include file="includes/header.html" %>     
<!-- fin inclure -->   

<div id="notification"><!-- zone de notification -->

</div>

<!--  Le contenu  -->
<div id="content">
    <form name="f">


<!--  draw the map Here  -->
         <div id="right">

        </div> 

    <div id="left">
        <a onclick="drawMap()">Click Here</a>

        <input type="date" placeholder="Date debut jj-mm-aaaa" name="dateDeb" id="dateDeb">&rarr;<input type="date"placeholder="Date Fin jj-mm-aaaa" name="dateFin"id="dateFin">
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div class="scrollbar-b">

        <table class="newspaper-a" summary="">
    <caption>Liste des Automobile en lignes</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Matriculation</th>
            <th scope="col">Marque</th>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>

           <tbody id="onLine">

           </tbody>
         </table>  
       </div>  <br/><br/>   
       <div class="scrollbar-b">       
        <table class="newspaper-a" summary="">
    <caption>Liste des Automobile hors lignes</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Matriculation</th>
            <th scope="col">Marque</th>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>

           <tbody id="offline">

           </tbody>
         </table>  

        </div>
    </div>  




    </form>
</div>      
<!--  Fin contenu  -->    


<!-- iclure le footer-->
<%@include file="includes/footer.html" %>   
<!-- fin iclure-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Error message?

Comment: I think we might be able to understand the other code.  Plus if you post we might be able to see something simple like a typo...

Comment: Nothing any more(blank page)...

Comment: the inner container might not get enough space because #a will be set to height and width 0 in my humble opinion

Comment: I simply copy and pasted this code and I don't see any errors.. *what is the **problem***?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe The code as is works, the problem is when you wrap the map_canvas div

Comment: I see now, when I copied, I haven't added an id to the wrapping div

Comment: @SmartyTwiti: Good job of creating good reduction that we can look at. For the next question, to make it perfect, you can put that reduction into a jsfiddle like I did. Also be sure to mention what the problem is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the 100%-sized map container is originally bounded by the window as the root element. But when you nest it inside another div, it's now bounded by *that* div, which is much smaller (ie 0).

You need to make the outer div bigger, too:

```
#a, #map_canvas { height: 100% ; width:100%;}
^^^
```

Comment: @Smarty - this type of issue can be tough to figure out. You might find that the browser dev tools are very helpful to see what's going on (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks Michael,  can you try with my new code? (question Updated).

Comment: @SmartyTwiti if you're having a different issue, I suggest opening a new question. You'll get better help that way

Comment: @MichaelHaren, okay , it seems that the issue from CSS , i'll  try changing some CSS.... Thanks still your answer helped me :) .